# What could be the reason that my node syncs so slowly during Header Synchronization?

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization, windows

I¹ am trying to sync Bitcoin Core v24.0.1 on my Desktop with 16 GB RAM and an Intel Core i7-7700HQ processor, but it is taking forever even to get past the header synchronization. It tells me that it will take over 3.5 years to synchronize.

[image]

3 hours later, my node is still in Header Synchronization:
[image]

- I have a decent internet connection and am connected to my router via wifi
- I downloaded Bitcoin Core v24.0.1 from bitcoincore.org
- I’m using an internal hard drive
- I have ten connections, but have only received about 340 kB across my eight outbound connections in the past ~10 minutes minutes [image]
- I have tried to add a few nodes from bitnodes.io via `addnode <ip> onetry` to perhaps learn about more peers (and the added nodes show up when I call `getaddednodeinfo` as past connections)
- I have over 365 GB of free disk space

### Update:

- My node was already configured to run in pruning mode
- I’ve increased my dbcache to 10 GB
- My debug.log appears to show that I’m switching my peers frequently [image]

Any ideas what else I should try?

---

¹Asking for a friend.

Comment: What has changed in the next few hours? Has the header synchronization finished? Has anything progressed?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing your `bitcoin.conf` settings and `debug.log`, it is difficult to say. Generally speaking, however, here are a few things:

- 365GB is not enough space, so you'll have to run in pruned mode or upgrade your hard drive
- SSD drives tend to be much faster than HDD drives when performing IBD
- `dbcache` is 450MiB by default. If you have 16GB of RAM available, you can set `dbcache` to a much higher value to help speed up IBD
- If you are pruning, make sure to set your `dbcache` and `prune` values to be similar. If your `prune` value is lower than your `dbcache` value, your node will not use all the available memory. See [Does pruning during IBD reduce the ability to utilize the dbcache fully?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/116653/does-pruning-during-ibd-reduce-the-ability-to-utilize-the-dbcache-fully) for more information

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, headers sync should not be taking 3 hours. Based on https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/26391 , it sounds like corrupted block data could be the cause. If you can confirm that by looking in your `debug.log`, restarting your node with `-reindex` is an option. However, it's difficult to recommend a solution without knowing what's in your `debug.log` first.

Comment: That's good general advice, but i don't think using a SSD or increasing the dbcache applies here: it's apparently stuck at syncing headers.

Comment: Ah, I missed the "3 hours" comment in the OP. Do you know how long headers sync should take normally?

Comment: A handful of minutes. :/ (Well, depend on the bandwidth but they disclaimed having a decent connection.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not collecting and insepcting debug logs? There could be traces of the reasons that the node is synchornising slowly. Upload a debug.log file generated by Bitcoin Core started with the -debug option, i.e.

> .\bitcoin-qt.exe -debug

3 hours of headers synchronisation doesn't seem to be slow to me.

Comment: The headers are less than 65 MB. Header Sync should take no more than a few minutes.